# How to check if the token is not expired?

Tags: php, hash

I am trying to generate a token which is combination of pre-defined-key, username & time valid for 30 minutes. This token is then emailed.

```
$minutesToAdd = 30;
$timeString = new \DateTime();
$timeString->add(new \DateInterval('PT' . $minutesToAdd . 'M'));
$result = $timeString->format('YmdHi');

$key = 'secret-key';
$combination = $key . '|' . 'zzz' . '|' . $result;

$hash = hash("sha256", $combination);
```

Now I need to verify that token is still valid.

What I did is from db, I fetched the username and then make a combination in a loop

```
$current = (new DateTime())->format('YmdHi');
$newCombination = $key . '|' . $username_from_db . '|' . $current;
$myHashed = hash("sha256", $newCombination);

if (hash_equals($hash, $myHashed)) {
  echo "Password matches.";
} else {
  echo "Password incorrect.";
}
```

When I don't have to add time, this was working but as a new requirement, I have make the token valid for 30 minutes. I am not sure how to do it.

Can anybody please help.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you also put the timestamp in the hash, why not generate all possible valid tokens?

Comment: Otherwise, why not store the generated tokens + their expiry timestamp in the database? This could also help to enhance the security, as you could properly invalidate tokens

Comment: Or have a look at https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/04/create-and-verify-jwts-in-php - signing the unhashed payload can help to **read** the payload

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add separate database column where you can maintain date and time of hash creation and check if it is older than 30 minutes while verifying the token. If it was created before 30 mins then, the token is expired.